# Music player freezes when I switch to one of the terminal window until I login to that terminal

Tags: command-line, banshee

Whenever I switch to a terminal window from my X window, (by pressing Ctrl+Alt+1) my music player (banshee) running in X freezes until I login to the terminal window. Once I login into it (or either switch back to my X with or without logging into it) the music player resumes from the point it freezed.

However, I observed that when am transferring files from my laptop to another computer over ssh and if I switch to one of the terminal windows, the transfer does not pause even if I don`t login to the termianl window.

I just wanted to know what could possibly be the reason for such a discrimination.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean switching to tty ( usually by Ctrl+Alt+F1 ), then reason of this behavior is pulseaudio running in "user mode"... it was discussed here, maybe it will help

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/213149